# Is the long-range communication device shown in SGU human-built?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

I've recently begun rewatching Stargate Universe (SGU) and something that's struck me on the very first episode was the design of the communication "pad" that the ancient stones are placed on ...
[image: SGU com pad]
[image: SGU com pad 2]

Everything about the design above screams American taxpayer dollars. The device looks like it could've been torn from a wall somewhere in the Prometheus. It's even got a red LED and some multicolor wire strips on its edges. Compare it to the ancient communication device seen in SG1 and SGA ...
[image: SG1 com dev]

It is often said throughout SGU that they don't fully understand how the communication device works, but perhaps they know enough to build the console/pad that facilitates the transfer? Is the communication pad shown throughout SGU human-built technology? Is SGU the only SG series in which this thing is shown?

Comment: In pretty sure that idea is that they've retro-engineered the device but not the stones.

Comment: I cant remember, but are they using the same pad/devices back on Earth? Or do they have another of the Ancient Communication devices (seen in the 3rd picture) back on Earth?

Comment: @NJohnny I believe they use the same kind of pad as on Destiny. Perhaps they built them to get around the issue of accidentally connecting with random folks in other galaxies (like what had happened to Daniel and Vala). Or maybe there plenty of stones and not enough communication devices to go around.

Comment: Were the stones used in the first episode of SGU?

Comment: @NJohnny Yeah. Dr. Rush used the pad (and presumably a stone) to connect with Earth in the first episode.

Comment: According to the stargate fandom  wiki, (I dont know how cannon it is) the new device IS human built. https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Long-range_communication_device#Tau.27ri_device

Comment: @NJohnny Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a source for the claim, but it's probably a safe bet. In some shots you can even see a couple of USB ports on the thing.

Answer (score -1):

The piece of hardware that the stones were placed on was an interface that the Tau'ri (humans) developed with Goa'uld and/or Asgard technology, based on how it appears and how small it is. It can be safely said that it contains very little (if any) Ancient technology given its connection is disruptible by Destiny's FTL drive.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include some supporting evidence, such as relevant screenshots or quotes.